# Read an xlsx file from a NAS (smbConnection)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pysmb

I'm trying to read an xlsx file stored in a NAS, using smb.SMBConnection.
I did this :

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
import tempfile

conn = SMBConnection('username', 'password', 'name', 'name')
conn.connect('10.111.111.111')
results = conn.listPath('shared_folder_name', 'path')
for x in results:
    print(x.filename)
```

And I read successfully the files of the folder.
But I wand to import one of them on a pandas dataframe.
How can I do that ?

I created a tempory file but failed to read it.

```
file_obj = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
file_name = file_obj.name
file_attributes, copysize = conn.retrieveFile('data', "path/data.xlsx", file_obj)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried to read it with?

Comment: I would suggest, simply mount/map a network drive to, lets say, letter Z if you use windows and move from that point